# Prevent 3rd party warnings from cluttering the log file

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

We are using several 3rd party libraries over which we do not have any control. One of them throws a org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException as a WARNING in our log files. It does not impact anything apart from cluttering our log files. Is there any way to suppress these warnings from our log files ?
We are using sl4j logging.
Thanks in advance.

Changing the logging levels to OFF for the package in 3rd party jar does not work out?
I read somewhere that I would need to change the logging level in the 3rd party jar. But I cannot modify the 3rd party jar.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation of Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and configure the logger to restrict the message of those packages to a higher logging level.

Comment: I tried setting the log level to FATAL, ERROR and also OFF. Still doesnt work. Is there a different solution. The warning message is basically thrown deep within the 3rd party code.